# The border disappears when opacity is added to the image

Tags: html, css

I want to display the image on mouse-over and keep the border.
However, when I add opacity, the border disappears as well. How can I maintain the border while displaying the image on mouse-over?"

Here is my code:

```
<div class="finishedprojects">
<img src="https://shorturl.at/bR589">
 </div>

 .finishedprojects img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: solid yellow 1em;
  background-color: black;
  opacity:0;
}


.finishedprojects img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

I tryed.finishedprojects img {
border: solid yellow 1em}
But it doesn't work.

Comment: If the border is on an element that you hide (with `opacity`, `display`, `visibility` or other) then the border will be hidden along with the element; what did you think would happen, and why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ::before pseudo-element to create a border on the image container that will not be affected by the opacity change on hover.

```
.finishedprojects {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 350px;
  height: 250px;
  border: solid yellow 1em;
  background-color: black;
}

.finishedprojects img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0;
}

.finishedprojects:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.finishedprojects::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid yellow 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to set `width: max-content;` in your container class  `.finishedprojects` and also move the border styling there. See my snippet:

```css
.finishedprojects  {
    width: max-content;
    border: solid yellow 1em;
}

.finishedprojects img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 350px;
    height: 250px;
    object-fit: cover;
    background-color: black;
    opacity:0;
}

.finishedprojects img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="finishedprojects">
    <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/lego/1.jpg" alt="Demo Image">
</div>
```

If you also want to have a black background if no image is displayed, move the background property `background-color: black;` from
`.finishedprojects img` class to the `.finishedprojects` class.